# Can't find static files for the Django admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin, django-staticfiles, django-1.5

I can't find an answer to what seems like a simple question.

I have a `Django 1.5` app on Heroku using `staticfiles`. The static files defined within my app can be found fine:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py findstatic bootstrap.min.css
Running `python manage.py findstatic bootstrap.min.css` attached to terminal... up, run.5557
Found 'bootstrap.min.css' here:
  /app/myapp/static/bootstrap.min.css
```

But the static files for the built-in admin interface can't be found, e.g.

```
$ heroku run python manage.py findstatic base.css  
Running `python manage.py findstatic base.css` attached to terminal... up, run.4546
No matching file found for 'base.css'.
```

The relevant bit of my settings is, I guess, this:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

For clarity, everything else on the admin interface works, but not the static CSS files. If I visit the admin login page, the server logs have:

```
No such file or directory: 'staticfiles/admin/css/base.css'
No such file or directory: 'staticfiles/admin/css/login.css'
```